# pinterest save button doesn't work if redirect from http to https is on

Tags: .htaccess, pinterest

[Pinterest could not fetch the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394573/pinterest-could-not-fetch-the-image)

I found a similar problem, it is proposed to exclude pinterest.com from a redirect, but it doesn't help. when I try use Pinterest save button I see error message "Something went wrong Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please try again" please help to fix it

browser console

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: [DenzelError] {"name":"DenzelError","code":"API_ERROR","http_status":400,"api_error_code":1,"target":null,"stack_trace":null,"extra_data":null,"request_identifier":null}
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(?:pinterest.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

button code

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?description=description&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Fimages%2Fproduct%2Fsmall%2Fimage.gif&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside">
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_round_red_32.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't help*? Please describe the error and the expected behavior.

Comment: error -- when I try use Pinterest save button I see error message "Something went wrong Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please try again".expected behavior -- share image in Pinterest

Answer (score 0):

support response:
1)A Pinterest crawler can only crawl to a website is A certified in SSL tool https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
2)Pinterest's IP is dynamic and thus constantly changing, but will always be in the range of: 54.236.1.XXX

In .htaccess file I added new exception for pinterest.com for https redirect by IP. 
    Now it looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(?:pinterest.com)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54\.236\.1\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```